# Is there a way to set a paging file on a folder-mounted volume in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mount, ntfs, virtual-memory, pagefile

I have a physical volume mounted to an NTFS folder in Windows 7 that I would like the system to use for paging. Is this possible and, if so, how do I enable it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm going to say probably not. the page file must be initialized very early in the boot process, since almost everything that executes expects virtual memory to be up and available.

Comment: To another drive yes. To a folder, probably not. See here for details ==> http://www.worldstart.com/move-your-windows-7-pagefile-to-a-new-location/